# ASP.net MVC create model with value with multiple options

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

I am wanting to create a Model that has a property of Service which then has multiple options that can either be true or false. So my Contact Class:

```
public class Contact
{
    //My Properties
}
```

I want the Contact class to have a property of Services. I have a list of services available. How can I reference my services from my Contact class. I would like be able to access it in my view like: `model.services.MyCustomService` if it's even possible. I come from a javascript background so this is what I mean but written in javascript if it helps.

**Javascript Example**

```
var Contact = {
    property: "",
    services: {
        MyCustomService: "",
        MyCustomService2: "",
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to bind to a collection of model objects ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I am still new to MVC and trying to get a grasp on it and the terminology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

In your Model:

```
public class Contact
{
    //My Properties

    public List<Service> Services
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In your Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Contact(); // Create model

    // Create some sample services
    var service = new Service();
    var service2 = new Service();

    // Add the services
    model.Services.Add(service);
    model.Services.Add(service2);

    // Pass the model to the view
    return View(model);
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
@model MySite.Models.Contact

@foreach (var service in Model.Services)
{
    <text>Here's my service: @service.MyCoolProperty.ToString()</text>
}
```

In that simple example, I first **declared the Services property of your Contact class as a `List<Service>`**. That allows you to combine many Services into one property - perfect for passing along to a view.

Next, in the Controller, I added some Services to the List by using the `Add()` method. Therefore, in the View, you're now able to **access those Services through `Model.Services`**.

To me, that looks like one of the simplest ways to approach this common problem. Hope that helped!

Comment: Great! That is pretty simple. Thank you for you help. I have to say I love ASP.NET I am new to it and it's has been awesome learning it.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, every object has a type so `Services` property has to have an actual *type* if you want to reference `MyCustomService` and `MyCustomService2` through dot notation:

```
class Contact {
    public ServiceContainer Services { get; set; }
}

class ServiceContainer {
    public Service1 Service1 { get; set; }
    public Service2 Service2 { get; set; }
}
```

However, if container serves for no other purpose but to store a service (assuming it's some object), you should probably store them in a list or array (access by index) or in a dictionary (access by string).

To give you more information, I'll need to know *what* exactly these services are, whether you expect their set to change, do they have different types, etc.

Comment: Each service will have the exact same properties and each service is read-only.

Comment: Are they all of the same type? If so, you should use a list or dictionary, kind of `Dictionary<string, Service>`.

Answer (score 0):

To bind to a collection all you need is this:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="ViewPage<IList<Book>>" %>
```

A complete explanation can be found here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: How can I go about this. I updated my question with my new classes how do I bind it to my original class. Thanks.

Comment: I think i may not explained myself very well I'll rewrite my question and see what you can tell me.